# How to locate a parent folder?

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems

How am I supposed to go back up 1 level to find a file?

I was trying code bellow but It's not working

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '../client-side/public/index.html');
});
```

**This is my folder structure**

[image]

Trying to go public folder under client-side folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `+` which essentially outputs this path:

```
'/[__dirname]../client-side/public/index.html'
```

Try using `path` module:

```
const path = require("path")

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../client-side/public/index.html'));
});
```

You can read more about `path.join()` in the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_join_paths)